# We cannot locate a server to load the workbook data model

Tags: excel, sql, powerpivot

This is the error that appears when I try to refresh data. I have been struggling with this issue for a few weeks. Researching in internet but with no luck. My sharepoint site is 2013 and SQL Server 2012 SP1, all over windows 2008 R2.

Any help from you will be extremely appreciate.

Thanks

Efrain Prada[image]

Comment: Have you tried this? http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2769345 or these suggestions: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/3870.troubleshooting-powerpivot-data-refresh.aspx?Sort=MostUseful&PageIndex=1#Issue_Cannot_Locate_a_server_to_load_a_workbook  I'm also experiencing the same issue.  These suggestions might work for you even though they didn't for me.

Comment: I solved the issue in my environment.  The problem was that the service account used for the Excel Services Application needed to be set as an Analysis Services administrator.  This is one of the suggestions http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/3870.troubleshooting-powerpivot-data-refresh.aspx?Sort=MostUseful&PageIndex=1#Issue_Cannot_Locate_a_server_to_load_a_workbook under the heading "Data Refresh Errors with SQL Server PowerPivot for SharePoint 2013"

Comment: Also a reboot was required.