# PowerPivot We cannot locate a server

Tags: 2013, powerpivot

I am having the same issue. I tried everything above as well as what was suggested here:

http://blog.qumsieh.ca/2013/08/19/ssas-sharepoint-2013-we-cannot-locate-a-server-to-load-the-workbook-data-model/

I also rebooted the server but still the same error.

Comment: I'm unable to read anything on that site.Could you please include more detail here? Detailed error messages, details about what you have tried, etc

Comment: I am receiving the following error when attempting to load a PowerPivot workbook in the browser "We cannot locate a server to load the workbook data model. It is the same issue this user is experiencing:  http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/76383/we-cannot-locate-a-server-to-load-the-workbook-data-model

Comment: I have verified that I do have the Analysis Services server configured correctly in Central Admin and that the service account has admin privileges on the server. I can connect to the Analysis Services instance through SSMS as well. Here is what I am getting in the ULS logs: Failed to create an external connection or execute a query. Provider message: There are no servers available or actively being initialized., ConnectionName: , Workbook: http://shrptd-v/sites/bi/Datawarehouse%20Monthly%20Reports/Accession%20Samples%20Report.xlsx.